# How to update two remote repositories with the same local repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a gitlab repository (origin) which is updated with my local repository. I also have a github repository (github), which is added in .git/config file, but is not updated (last commit is for many times ago).
Now I want to use git status for github rep, to see which files have been changed and then add, commit and push.
I used `git branch --set-upstream-to github/master` to set the upstream to github and then I used `git status`. But what it shows, is the same git status of gitlab repository (origin) while it is written:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'github/master'.
```

I know that there are a lot of files need to be pushed but it says there are no changes.
What is the problem?
The other question is how can I add and commit each file to the 'github/master' repository?

Comment: `git status` doesn't connect to any remote - it just shows status relative to what the local repo already knows of a remote's state. Run `git fetch github` to refresh Git's knowledge of the current state of the `github` remote, and then `git status` will show you the relative status of local and remote.

Comment: @JimRedmond I tried fetch command but the result is the same as before. It seems that git is not refreshed.